# just got my pi working

Tags: raspbian

i got it to run properly a few times it downloaded  some improvements got the wifi working 
now the pi will not "boot up" when i start the pi the four rasberry's come on and the program is desplayed on the screen s it opens up and it seems like just before it will open all the way ,,,,,,,i can nor read it that well,,, i think is says something like the program  is license  for only 5 times,
 i am using the rasbian program off of rasberrypi.org sight

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But please write more than one endless sentence. It is hard to read and for me too stressful so I don't read it. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Please be so kind and edit your question to include vital details about your problem... and give the question a meaningful title. Thanks.

Comment: i got the pi working had to reload program working ok

Answer (score 1):

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151 covers most reasons why your RPi won't boot.

You need to be sure you got the right version of Raspbian from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full_latest